# Create controller logic for ASP.Net MVC for logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following models:

```
public class Expense
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal Limit { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

I have a logged in user, and I would like that user to be able to add new Expenses. The create controller actions looks as follows:

```
    //
    // GET: /Expenses/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Expenses/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Expense expense)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.Single(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
            user.Expenses.Add(expense);                
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(expense);
    }
```

With the view:

```
@model MoneyDrainPlug.Models.Expense

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Expense</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Limit)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Limit)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Limit)
        </div>        
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

When the post happens, ModelState.IsValid is false in the controller. This is because the there is no UserProfileId set in the expense. It does not help if I set the UserProfile and\or UserProfileId before calling ModelState.IsValid.

What would be the correct and secure way of handling this? Surely I should not trust a UserProfileId sent from the client?

In case it matters, I am using asp.net MVC 4.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions

remove the `Required` attribute on `UserProfileId` (DataAnnotation is just related to views : if you don't want something in your views, don't mark it as `Required` : `RequiredAttribute` is not a DB constraint)

or

remove the `UserProfileId` property (you have the `UserProfile` proeprty, it's probably enough)

or

create a `ViewModel` without the `UserProfileId` property

EDIT :
To be clear : you can perfectly use a ViewModel. Just be conscient that Required attributes have nothing to do directly with your DB. If you don't use the `Expense` class directly in a view, you can remove all your `Required` attributes in `Expense`, they will never be used.

Comment: Thanks. The `UserProfileId` is a dbconstraint, it is required. I may be wrong but think I need both `UserProfile` and `UserProfileId` for entity framework to work correctly. I guess I could use a view model, I would still need to validate the expense though. I could try saving it and catch exceptions as per here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx.

Comment: @Daryn It may be a DbConstraint, but the RequiredAttribute is not related with db constraints. It's related to views ("what fields must be setted when my form is submitted"). If you load your UserProfile in your controller, your DB will be ok, that's all. And no, EF don't need both. You may use a ViewModel.

Comment: @Daryn Also keep in mind that as long as UserProfileId is part of your model, and you are using model-binding (i.e. ActionResult Create(Expense expense)), that value can be sent by the client - even when it's not in your view (read hacker).  I agree with @Raphael; remove the [Required] attribute and set it explicitly in your Action, so as to override any value that was sent by the client.

Comment: Thanks, I will do something along these lines: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx

Answer (score 1):

for one, You should make sure those pages can only be accessed by authorized users (Add [Authorize] above every method in the controller that requires the user to be logged in)

There are a couple of ways actually of doing this:

One would be **a hidden field** with the name UserProfileId and value of the logged in users Id
This would be the least safe method of doing it as the Id will be posted from the client to the server therefor it could be manipulated by the client.

I notice that those fields have the required annotation so either **you remove the [Required] to make it validate** OR you make **a new viewmodel** with all those attributes without having UserProfileId required (and obviously you dont include the virtual attribute as it isnt needed in this case).

It would turn out to something like this:

```
public class ExpenseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Limit { get; set; }
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

As a final touch, you change the model that the view expects:

```
@model MoneyDrainPlug.Models.ExpenseModel
```

And the model the controller expects to recieve after a post:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ExpenseModel expense)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.Single(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
            _expense = new Expense() { Name = expense.Name, Limit = expense.Limit, UserProfile = user };
            user.Expenses.Add(_expense);                
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(expense);
    }
```